# How to write JellyTools functional tests?

Tags: java, netbeans, functional-testing

I managed to set up JellyTools in my Java project in Netbeans Platform. Now I would like to write some functional tests with it but I can't find any tutorials about JellyTools apart from this:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/JellyTools

Can anyone give me some tips about it or post some other tutorials?

I would like to write a text in a textfield for example and then press the button "Next" in a wizard but I couldn't manage to do it with the tutorial above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my own question about writing a text in a wizard and then press "Next". This way I can create a project automaticaly in my application:

```
    Action action = new Action("File|New Project", null);
    action.perform();
    WizardOperator wo = new WizardOperator("New Project");
    wo.next();

    JTextFieldOperator txtName = new JTextFieldOperator(
            (JTextField) new JLabelOperator(wo, "Project Name:").getLabelFor());
    txtName.clearText();
    txtName.typeText("MyProject");
    wo.finish();
```

Comment: any example of simply finding a Button and clicking it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adrian, 
Jelly tools is intended to create UI tests for Netbeans IDE itself, so it is not expected to use it for test Your UI. You can try Jemmy module which is also base layer for Jelly.
You can see some Jemmy tutorials there: https://jemmy.java.net/tutorial.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the info :) I will take a look to this Jemmy tutorial.

Comment: Also I found that exist JellyTools IDE and JellyTools Platform. So as you said, JellyTools IDE is intended to create UI test for Netbeans IDE itself but with JellyTools Platform I could test an application that I'm creating with Netbeans.

Comment: All of them, JellyTools, Jelly IDE and Platform are for Netbeans UI testing. JellyTools IDE covers different Netbeans UI parts like Editor window, tabs, other windows, etc. Jelly Platform provides access to different NB actions like actions, properties, nodes.